# Marklogic: How to load XML documents into Marklogic in the same order as it was ordered in the source file

Tags: xml, marklogic, reload

I'm running a set of xqueries on data stored in **marklogic**. when I saw the results, I noticed that data records are not ordered in the same order as it was ordered in the file that I have load it from.  I used flow studio for loading my `xml` documents into marklogic. I need the files to be in the same order as it was ordered in the source file. Is there a way to achieve that? **OR** IF this is not possible sorting documents in in an **ascending** order will solve my problem. how to do so? NOTE:
I want to to order xml documents not xquery results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MarkLogic does not store records in an particular order. That said, as records are ingested, you could add a property or metadata element that could be used. For example, when I load rows from a CSV, I typically make sure each row has a unique, ordered ID if I want to be able to represent the data in that order again.

Regardless, you're going to need to return ordered results based on the query you use to retrieve the records, as you ask in the second part of your question.

When using FLOWR to query the data, you'll be able to use the `order by ascending` clause to order the documents by the desired value.

It can get a little more involved when you're returning search:search() or cts:search() results, but the underlying logic is similar. There's important performance considerations when trying to order search results- typically you're going to want a range index on the sort element. There's plenty of information in the ML documentation, depending on how you're querying the records you want to order.

XQuery order by clause: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/xquery/langoverview#id_71283

Performance guide:
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/order_by

Sort-order in search:search()
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_44212

Comment: I want to to order xml documents not xquery results

Comment: What do you mean by "order xml documents?" The way I read this, you have a source file that contains records which are ingested as separate documents in the database. Do you mean the source is a single xml record and the document order of the elements in the resulting database doc is not the same as the document order for the source?

Comment: the source is the file that i have loaded xml documents from it to marklogic.

Comment: Not trying to be a pain...I want to understand the scenario so I can make sure you have a direction to go in. What format is the source file? Is there one record in the MarkLogic for each source file? Or are there many records in MarkLogic for each source file?

Comment: As Harry already mentioned, there is no natural order of data inside the database. By default results of cts:search are ordered by relevance. If you don't want that, you will have to explicitly tell MarkLogic to sort differently. The easiest way is setup a range index, and use [cts:index-order](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:index-order)..

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/39229117/918496 for a small example..

Comment: The problem is that I'm not using  `cts:search` in my code. I'm using **FLOWR** to query data.

Comment: Still possible, but harder to make use of range indexes for sorting. See this section in the performance guide: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/order_by#id_29515

Comment: The O in FLOWR stands for Order by (and it's all XQuery). The first link I shared in my answer is a simple example. Here's a slightly more detailed example- http://www.stylusstudio.com/xquery-flwor.html  Good luck...